# How to do this function about scale ,rotate and translate use matrix with flutter

Tags: matrix, flutter, rotation, scale

Can you help me with this function?

Single finger control image rotation/zoom/panning is achieved using matrix4 on the flutter platform.

Rendings show: https://upload-images.jianshu.io/upload_images/679754-2b1038c06a4712b0.gif

Comment: why dont you want to do that in a natural way by using two fingers?

Comment: Thank you, but I have already achieved it. Happy

Comment: with single finger